# Cancel long-running Ray tasks without cancelling pending tasks

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, ray

Using Ray in Python, I am doing a numerical simulation on 1000 elements running in parallel (on a PC with 8 cores). Sometimes the simulation gets stuck, and I would like to cancel the tasks that run for more than 90 seconds with `ray.cancel()`, so the rest of the elements in the queue can be processed. I can use `ray.wait()` to check if any simulations are finished and then process them, and I understand that best practice is to use a loop with `ray.wait()` instead of `ray.get()`. But among the unfinished tasks, I don't know how to distinguish between long-running tasks and pending tasks. As a workaround, I am thinking of using `ray.get(elem, timeout = 90)` in a for loop, and then cancelling the tasks that don't finish within the timeout, like this:

```
import ray
from ray.exceptions import GetTimeoutError
ray.init()

# Create jobs in element_list
# ...

# Collect finished jobs
finished = []
cancelled = []
for elem in element_list: 
  try: 
    finished.append(ray.get(elem,timeout=90))
  except GetTimeoutError:
    ray.cancel(elem,force=True)
    cancelled.append(elem)
```

Is this the best way to do a thing like this? Or is it possible to get a list of the executing tasks and their running times? Or would it be possible to have a timer internally in the task that would return after 90 seconds without a solution? I am using a differential equation solver (scipy.integrate.solve_ivp), so it's not so easy to do a timeout check internally in the task.

Edit:
I think [this thread](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/15672) is discussing the same problem. And [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/18916) is a feature request for the same thing. I will look into them.